# phpgraphlib A non-numeric value encountered for php version 7.1

Tags: php, phpgraphlib

I was using [PHPGraphLib](https://github.com/elliottb/phpgraphlib) for my php version 7.0 and it was working absolutely fine. However, I have switched my local server from 7.0 to 7.1 and now it has started giving me an error saying..

> A non-numeric value encountered
>
> at /my_website_path/phpgraphlib.php line 987

Hence I went to this particular line and found this code at line number **987**.

```
$raw_size = $high_x - $low_x +1;
```

And changes this chunk of code to this (Ref https://github.com/elliottb/phpgraphlib/issues/30#issuecomment-394975371 ).

```
raw_size = $data[$high_x] - $data[$low_x] +1;
```

And I have successfully surpassed this error. But now I am getting another error saying..

> A non-numeric value encountered
>
> at /my_website_path/phpgraphlib.php line 381

I went here and found this code.

```
$xStart = $this->y_axis_x1 + ($this->space_width / 2) + ((key($data_set) - $this->lowest_x) * ($this->bar_width + $this->space_width));
```

And tried to replace with this code.

```
$xStart = (float) $this->y_axis_x1 + ((float) $this->space_width / 2) + ( (float) (key(  $data_set) -  (float) $this->lowest_x) * ((float) $this->bar_width + (float) $this->space_width));
```

Yes I am unable to make it work in my php version 7.1

I have tried to find ways and researched but yet to find which works for me.

I have also tried to search this library which is working for 7.1 but it seems like they have not upgraded to php 7.1 yet.

Can someone guide me how can I overcome these issues and make it somehow work for my latest php version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have resolved the error following below thread.

https://github.com/LupenWonse/phpgraphlib/commit/ae815920d0790b11da28763ff599462740389097

Hope this helps.